# Android tablets and Bluetooth HFP

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

I am writing an application that records audio from a bluetooth headset. I have been testing on my HTC Evo 4g LTE(4.0.3). The headset pairs and the application works as intended. To further my testing I am trying to connect a bluetooth headset to a few Android Tablets. The headset pairs just fine, but then it is unable to connect. I'm not given an error dialog, but selecting the headset from my list of paired devices has no response.  My hypothesis is that the Handsfree profile was removed from both of these devices because of the lack of phone included inside of them. The devices I have tested on include the Asus Nexus 7 (4.1) and the Motorola Xoom(4.0).

Considering my hypothesis is correct, is there a way to package an application with that missing HFP bluetooth profile without requiring root access?

Comment: Probably not even root access. The profile is not a file or anything you can simply put on a device. It has to be supported from hardware up the whole software chain. The bluetooth driver for example might be missing that functionality. Chances raise that manufacturers don't implement it if it's no phone but tablet is not really an excuse.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a way of adding bluetooth profiles to a device. As zapl pointed out: I think it has to be supported by the specific android device.
But as for the Nexus 7 there's HFP included: http://support.google.com/nexus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2739735


So i assume your problem isn't caused by missing HFP. Maybe it's due to the inappropriate role of this profile. The spec defines two different roles: The Audio Gatewy (AG) and the Hands-Free unit (HF). You must use the HF role on the device to use it as a headset. ([Bluetooth Hands-Free Profile](http://www.bluetooth.org/Building/HowTechnologyWorks/ProfilesAndProtocols/HFP.htm))

Unfortunately this role is not supported by the current [Android API](http://source-android.frandroid.com/external/bluetooth/bluez/doc/hfp-api.txt) ...